# stop groovy script execution

Tags: scripting, groovy

I have a groovy script file, that I run with GroovyShell. How to stop executing of script?
I tried put it in new thread and later interrupt thread but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another question here from last year asking a similar thing:

[Stopping the execution of a Groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035609/stopping-the-execution-of-a-groovy-script)

There is also a [ThreadInterrupt AST transform](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/ThreadInterrupt.html) which may help.  Also, see [the TimedInterrupt transform](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TimedInterrupt.html)